# How to store results of custom function in a df with a given name

Tags: r, function

**Disclaimer: this is my first attempt to write a function**

I'm working with airpolution data from web sources and I'm trying to write a function that will clean-up raw data and store it's results to a new `data.frame` (`tbl_df`) object.

I can't find out how to pass the name of the new object to be created as an argument to my function.

(any advices regarding optimizing my code would be welcome as well)

My function has to do the following:
- read raw data  (works)
- find all columns with commas as decimal values  (works)
- replace commas with dots and convert columns to numerics  (works)
- clean column names based on an argument (effectively: delete entire string after `-`)  (works)
- store results as a new object under new name (**not working**)

Here is some exemplary data I `dput()` sampled rows and columns from original data:

```
df <-
      structure(
            list(
                  `Czas pomiaru` = structure(
                        c(1462878000, 1452074400,
                          1475539200),
                        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
                        tzone = "UTC"
                  ),
                  `MpKrakBujaka-PM2.5-1g` = c("11,6384", "101,609", "11,329"),
                  `SkMalo11List-PM2.5-1g` = c("4,32", "42,4", "7,65"),
                  `DsJelGorOgin-PM2.5-1g` = c("7,98814",
                                              "56,1844", "6,2")
            ),
            .Names = c(
                  "Czas pomiaru",
                  "MpKrakBujaka-PM2.5-1g",
                  "SkMalo11List-PM2.5-1g",
                  "DsJelGorOgin-PM2.5-1g"
            ),
            row.names = c(NA,
                          -3L),
            class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
      )
```

My goal is to change data looking like this:

```
Observations: 3
Variables: 4
$ `Czas pomiaru`          <dttm> 2016-05-10 11:00:00, 2016-01-06 10...
$ `MpKrakBujaka-PM2.5-1g` <chr> "11,6384", "101,609", "11,329"
$ `SkMalo11List-PM2.5-1g` <chr> "4,32", "42,4", "7,65"
$ `DsJelGorOgin-PM2.5-1g` <chr> "7,98814", "56,1844", "6,2"
```

Into this:

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Czas.pomiaru: POSIXct, format: "2016-05-10 11:00:00" ...
 $ MpKrakBujaka: num  11.6 101.6 11.3
 $ SkMalo11List: num  4.32 42.4 7.65
 $ DsJelGorOgin: num  7.99 56.18 6.2
```

My best working example looks like this:

```
cleanGios<- function(pollutantCode, data, newObject){
      require(tidyverse)
      require(magrittr)
      data %<>%
            mutate_at(vars(contains("-")),
                      str_replace,
                      pattern = ",",
                      replacement = "\\.") %>%
            mutate_at(vars(contains("-")), funs(as.numeric))
      colNames <- data %>%
            names() %>%
            str_replace(pattern = pollutantCode, replacement = "")
      names(data) <- colNames
      newObject<<- data.frame(data)
}
```

After running

```
cleanGios("-PM2.5-1g", df, pm25_2016)
```

A new cleaned `tbl_df` is created but under a wrong name: `newObject` instead of `pm25_2016` as specified in function argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `mutate_at`, use `rename_at`

```
res <- df %>%
         mutate_at(vars(contains('-')), funs(as.numeric(str_replace(., ',', '.')))) %>%
         rename_at(vars(contains('-')), funs(str_replace(., '-.*', '')))

str(res)
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ Czas pomiaru: POSIXct, format: "2016-05-10 11:00:00" "2016-01-06 10:00:00" "2016-10-04 00:00:00"
#  $ MpKrakBujaka: num  11.6 101.6 11.3
#  $ SkMalo11List: num  4.32 42.4 7.65
#  $ DsJelGorOgin: num  7.99 56.18 6.2
```

---

Wrapping it in a function

```
cleanGios<- function(pollutantCode, data){
       data %>%
         mutate_at(vars(contains('-')), funs(as.numeric(str_replace(., ',', '.')))) %>%
         rename_at(vars(contains('-')), funs(str_replace(., pollutantCode, '')))
  }

cleanGios("-PM2.5-1g", df)
```

Comment: haha, that's way simpler and more elegant. I clearly overdid it. Thank you.